# TwoFactorAuthenticator GenerateSetupCode method in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, authentication, model-view-controller, two-factor-authentication

I have to tried to implement TwoFactorAuthenticator using google authenticator in ASP.NET MVC.

[image]

As per image I can't add QR code size width and height.

Comment: It looks like you are using an old tutorial... what is the method actually expection?

Comment: Oh yes, I fixed it my self, I have downgraded the version.
Thanks

Comment: In that case add your own answer - it might be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it my self, I have downgraded the version. 
Thanks

Comment: downgraded to which specific version?